# How to update value in a JavaScriptObject?

Tags: javascript, gwt

In my gwt application, I need to update the value of some fields in a JavaScriptObject. But it seems my following approach does not work.

```
public class ViewModel extends JavaScriptObject
{
    protected ViewModel() { } 

    public native final int getValue()
    /*-{ return this.value; }-*/;

    public native final int setValue(String val)
    /*-{ this.value = val}-*/;
}
```

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: what do you mean with "does not work"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setValue` takes a `String` where it probably should have been an `int` (given that `getValue` returns an `int`), and it's declared to return an `int` where it actually returns nothing (i.e. in JavaScript `undefined`).

In other words, it should be:

```
public native final int getValue() /*-{ return this.value; }-*/;

public native final void setValue(int val) /*-{ this.value = val; }-*/;
```